# How character array works

Tags: c, stdio

Try the below codes

**Program1**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=2;  //two times
    while(i>0)
    {
        char ch[2];  
        scanf("%s",ch);   
        printf("%s\n",ch);
        i--;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

output (loop never terminate and take and print any length of string)

```
wdefgfvcdswdfetgyhujik
wdefgfvcdswdfetgyhujik
nbvewsq
nbvewsq
hgbvfdw
hgbvfdw
hbgfvedw
hbgfvedw
gfvdcwsq
gfvdcwsq
.
.
.
```

output(loop terminates when it take the valid set of string)

```
a
a
b
b
```

**program2**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[2]; 
    scanf("%s",ch);   
    printf("%s\n",ch);

    return 0;
}
```

output(How does it print and say Segmentation fault)

```
sxdfvghujiuytredwsazxacdfv
sxdfvghujiuytredwsazxacdfv
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `char ch[2];` can't hold a string like `sxdfvghujiuytredwsazxacdfv` (in fact, it can hold only only one character and the null terminator). Entering those big strings is undefined behavior, and segmentation faults are a common manifestation of UB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Comment: Strings in C are null terminated and that's that.

Comment: @Blaze try this code https://onlinegdb.com/SymqyYEYB see line 17 event though the buf size is 4 it is working

Comment: @Blaze that's a wonderful example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding the first problem:**

If you will debug the program you can easily see that the endless loop is cause because you overwrite the `i` not using the `scanf` properly, the fix for the second problem should fix that to.

**Regarding the second problem:**

You are using the `scanf` function, which isn't safe due to the fact that it reads the entire input from user regardless of the size of buffer you allocated (in your case `char ch[2]`.

so although it does enters the entire string `sxdfvghujiuytredwsazxacdfv` to the `ch` it is obviously overflowing -> thus segmentation fault is inevitable.
Instead use `scanf_s` and restrict the amount of characters to read.

*Note:*

If youll raise warning flags it should appear that `scanf` is problematic and unsafe